# scp, inconsistency for file structure preservation

Tags: bash, scp, directory-structure

- My task: collect log files from several servers.
- Server file structure:  "/remote/path/dir/sub-dirs/files.log",  which
  is the same on all servers. (All servers have the same set of
  "sub-dirs", absence could happen, and of course "files.log" names
  differ)
- Local file structure:  "/local/path/logs"
- After copy I would like to have 
  "/local/path/logs/dir/sub-dirs/files.log"
- Method (in a whlile loop for servers):  scp -r
  $SERVERS:/remote/path/dir /local/path/logs
- Problem: For reasons I don't understand, the first scp command
  ignores the "dir" folder, I get "/local/path/logs/sub-dirs/files.log"
  But following scp commands gives me what I intended 
  "/local/path/logs/dir/sub-dirs/files.log"
- Why is this happening and how should I fix/get around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this happening [...]

In the command `scp -r path/to/source dest`:

- If `dest` doesn't exist, the `dest` directory will be created, and `path/to/source/*` will be copied into it. For example if you have `path/to/source/X` then `dest/X` will be created.
- If `dest` is a directory, then `dest/source` will be created, and the `path/to/source/*` will be copied into it. For example if you have `path/to/source/X` then `dest/source/X` will be created.

> [...] and how should I fix/get around it?

Create `dest` in advance, for example:

```
mkdir -p /local/path/logs
scp -r $SERVERS:/remote/path/dir /local/path/logs
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out a noob, Janos. Problem cleared now.